# Can't archive single data in init state from cloud firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want archive a number from cloud firestore in init state ..below is my code how am trying to archive but it not working ..can anyone tell me how to do that ........

```
int _prvScore ;

//  @protected
//  @mustCallSuper
//  void initState() {
//    _prvScore = 23.toInt();
//  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    var month = new DateTime.now().month;
    final DocumentReference documentReference =
    Firestore.instance.collection('quiz').document('$month')
        .collection('1')
        .document(username);
    subscription =
        documentReference.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
          if (datasnapshot.data.containsKey("total score")) {
            _prvScore = datasnapshot.data['total score'].toInt();
          }

    });



  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setState(...)` to cause a rebuild.
If you execute async code, the result will not yet be available when the function is completed and `build()` already executed.

Async code is only executed eventually later.

Changing

```
 _prvScore = datasnapshot.data['total score'].toInt();
```

to

```
setState(() => _prvScore = datasnapshot.data['total score'].toInt());
```

should fix it.

You need to ensure `build()` doesn't cause an error when `_prvScore` is still `null` because no data arrived yet from Firebase.

Comment: setstate work but its show me null ..can you please tell me the way to receive data in init state ..am searching for that and trying many way  but not receive

Comment: Sounds like "You need to ensure build() doesn't cause an error when _prvScore is still null" from my answer. When `build()` is run the first time, there is no value yet. Getting the value from the server takes some time. Just build some empty contentent when `_prvScore` is `null` and then the next time `build()` is called and `_prvScore != null` then build the real content.